# Emacs list function definitions popup like Sublime CMD + R

Tags: python, emacs

In Sublime Text (Mac OS X), you can do CMD + R shortcut to list function definitions in a popup. When you type function names, it does fuzzy matching to show matches. Press enter and go to the definition. I find it very handy.

In Emacs, is there something like that?

I'm using `elpy` for writing Python and  I found [`elpy-occur-definitions`](http://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#command-elpy-occur-definitions) (C-c C-o) which can show function definitions in a different buffer. Close. But not exactly what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: `M-x apropos-function`.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Good suggestion! I found [helm-imenu-anywhere] (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc11) which does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jenesaisquoi's comment, I found [helm-imenu-anywhere](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc11) 
which does exactly what I want.

I override this key-binding `M-r` (since I don't use the navigation function that often) which is also very close to Cmd-R.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") 'helm-imenu-anywhere)
```

UPDATE:

If you are on Mac OS X and want to use the same CMD + R to do this, you ca bind the key to `s-r` instead:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-r") 'helm-imenu-anywhere)
```

UPDATE 2:

I found that, to list functions in current buffer (versus out of all files), the best trick is `helm-semantic-or-imenu`. So my ultimate setup is

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-r") 'helm-semantic-or-imenu)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-o") 'helm-imenu-anywhere)
```